# how to order by date django post view

Tags: django, django-views

How can I order my posts from latest to oldest? I Use ordering = ['-date_posted'] for class based views. how can I do the exact thing for a function based view? 
this is my view function:

```
def blog_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    common_tags = Post.tags.most_common()[:]
    context = {
        'posts':posts,
        'common_tags':common_tags,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/blog.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
```

or in your models add a meta class

```
 class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
```